# How to initialize a FieldArray from state using redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Am using a redux-form FieldArray to allow user to create blocks of open times for their store on different days.

Working fine to add them, but once created, need to load a form on their 'Edit Store Open Times' section with initially created data in order to make changes later.

Can't figure out how to loop through returned information. The following works to create, but I need solution to pull in and print out the service blocks into fieldsets so user can edit and resubmit.

```
    renderGroups = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {fields.map((service, index) =>
            <div className="service-type-group" key={index}>
              <h4>{this.stringifyServiceNumbers(index + 1)} Service</h4>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="remove-button"
                onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>Remove
              </button>
              <div className="field-group third">
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.day`}
                  component={SelectField}
                  floatingLabelText="Day of week"
                  className="textfield">
                    <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Monday" />
                    <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Tuesday" />
                    <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Wednesday" />
                    <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Thursday" />
                    <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Friday" />
                    <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Saturday" />
                    <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="Sunday" />
                </Field>
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.fromTime`}
                  component={TimePicker}
                  defaultValue={null}
                  floatingLabelText="From"
                  className="textfield"
                />
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.untilTime`}
                  component={TimePicker}
                  defaultValue={null}
                  floatingLabelText="To"
                  className="textfield"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="field-group half">
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.service_type`}
                  component={SelectField}
                  floatingLabelText="Service type"
                  className="textfield">
                  <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="First-come first-served" />
                  <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Appointment" />
                </Field>
              </div>
              <div className="field-group sentence-inline">
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.peoplePer`}
                  type="number"
                  component={TextField}
                  label="Number of people per timeslot"
                  className="textfield"
                />
                <p>people are allowed every</p>
                <Field
                  name={`${service}.timeslotDuration`}
                  component={SelectField}
                  className="textfield">
                  <MenuItem value={0} primaryText="5 minutes" />
                  <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="10 minutes" />
                  <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="15 minutes" />
                  <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="30 minutes" />
                  <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="60 minutes" />
                  <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="All day" />
                </Field>
                <p>.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <button
            type="button"
            className="action-button"
            onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Service
          </button>
          {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

All other fields are populating correctly by fetching pantry data from api on ComponentWillMount. Just need that FieldArray information and markup.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values you pass to `initialValues` (or via a dispatched [`initialize()` action](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/)) need to be in the same structure as what `redux-form` gives you when you create the array from scratch. So, judging from your code, I'd say something like:

```
[
  { 
    day: 1, 
    fromTime: '10:00', 
    untilTime: '11:00', 
    service_type: 1, 
    peoplePer: 3,
    timeslotDuration: 4
  }
  { 
    day: 2, 
    fromTime: '12:00', 
    untilTime: '13:00', 
    service_type: 0, 
    peoplePer: 2,
    timeslotDuration: 2
  }
]
```

I've quickly coded up a simple example for you here, so you can see it working: [InitializeFromStateForm.js](https://gist.github.com/erikras/50b7b4bb4b4907b40a5ca9d99c2ff77e)